# Cut path between intersection of open paths in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

How do I cut the path between two intersecting lines? Cutting between paths that are closed seems to be easy (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPDFL_gAbW8), but how would you do it if the lines are open like in the following example?

In the example below I want to remove the line marked with a red arrow that is between two intersecting lines (each marked with a red circle)

[image: 1]

I tried to create a difference between these two elements, but then a new (blue) line is created.

[image]

So, basically, if I manage to delete one line another line is created and I have the same problem as before.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it: The trick is not to use division, difference or intersection but instead to use **union** 
[image]